# Enter Data into Pop-Up Window

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

I'm using VBScript to automate a time consuming process that involves several Access databases and Excel files.
One obstacle I am trying to overcome is dealing with pop-up windows generated by different Access macros.

**Problem 1:**

```
Dim objAccess
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "X:\Database1.accdb"
objAccess.DoCMD.RunMacro "Macro1"
```

Macro1 will update the database and a pop-up window will appear informing the user that the input process is complete. I want VBScript to `SendKeys "{Enter}"` to that pop-up window to close it.
I've tried many variants, including sending "{Enter}" before calling the macro with no success. Activating the window is also no solution.
The problem appears to be that WSH will wait for the macro to complete running, so I was looking into the parameters the `DoCMD.RunMacro` Method accepts, only to find that "waiting", Boolean, for the macro to complete running is not one of them.

**Problem 2:**

Macro2 will ask the user to enter a certain date. This date is stored in a variable and I want my script to enter that variable into the input box and "click" the ok button. Same concept as Problem 1. Since I'm stuck with Problem 1, can't solve Problem 2.

Disclaimer: Since the databases are used by several different users across departments, I'm not authorized to modify the macros in any way. I have to reproduce "human manual input".

Comment: VBScript doesn't support parallelism. You'd need to run the `SendKeys` script separately from the script invoking the macro. Note, however, that `SendKeys` is always a terrible last-resort kind of approach, since you barely have control over where the keystrokes actually are sent. Tools like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) are much better at this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks, I try to avoid `SendKeys` whenever I can, but I'm yet to find an alternative. Appreciate the AutoIt suggestion, but getting new software approved at this company is a horrendous procedure... It's been 3 weeks, and I still can't install notepad++...